# Facebook Login in Action Sheet

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is it possible to run login process on click on the action sheet item?

For example, now I have:

```
let facebookAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

}
```

and inside of it to place all login process, like I'm clicking on Login Button.

```
FBSDKLoginButton().delegate = self
FBSDKLoginButton().readPermissions = ["publish_actions"]
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your alertcontroller add action ok login button like below..

```
var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    //fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Browser

    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

      if (error == nil){
        var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
        {
            self.returnUserData()
            //fbLoginManager.logOut()
        }
    }
  })
```